# How to prepare label data for multiple bounding boxes which has a single class for object detection?

Tags: object-detection, bounding-box

I am trying to work on a object detection problem where I want to train the data with the provided image dataset. It has mask information for each image and some images have multiple bounding boxes. How could I prepare the label data with multiple bounding boxes so that I can use it for training.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of surfing and courtesy in one of the site, i got to know how to prepare the mask data. I created a zero numpy array as the size of the image and changed the values in the numpy array within the given bounding boxes to 1.

```
mask = np.zeros([image_height, image_width], dtype='float32')
for i in range(len(bboxes)):
     bbox = bboxes[i]
     x0, x1 = int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[3])
     y0, y1 = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[2])
     mask[x0:x1, y0:y1] = 1
```

bboxes is the bounding boxes for the data